# Bypass Symfony framework to display folder content

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

First of all. I haven't got any knowledge about Symfony. I just have to do a few modifications to an existing site quick and dirty. Now here is the case.
I need to "bypass" the Symfony framework to access static content in a folder e.g. (domain.com/folder).

This folder contains index.html and all the needed images, css, js etc. It also contains sub pages like (domain.com/folder/sub.html, domain.com/folder/sub2.html etc.). These sub pages are accessible thourgh domain.com/folder/index.html.

How can I do this?

**SOLVED: (by user3749178)**

Put you folder under `/web`. And a note for anyone else -> you also have to reference the file name.

domain.com/folder/ **-> does not work**

domain.com/folder/index.php **-> works**

Comment: You have to accept the user3749178 answer if has solved your problem

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for reminding me @gp_sflover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put you folder under `/web`. Everything what is in your `/web` directory is visible via http.